# Font in power/battery/wifi/applications has fuzzy shadow with OSX-Arc-White theme

Tags: release-juno, themes

I'm not sure how to explain this since I'm extremely new to using Linux, but after looking around for themes, I found OSX-Arc-White to be the exact theme I've wanted. The only issue is, the fonts in the menus have an extremely heavy fuzzy shadow which looks horrendous in my opinion.

[image] [image] [image]

My question is: Is there any way to change the font and it's settings in the theme pack or folder, and if so, where and how would I do it?

Here's the Github link to the theme pack

https://github.com/thiagolucio/OSX-Arc-Shadow

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Install elementary tweaks. That should enable you to change current system fonts, independent of themes.